# SetPropertyValueFactory of a TableColumn JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, factory, tablecolumn

Let's say I have a class called Employee.

Employee has a String name, int age, and a custom object Workstyle ethic. A Workstyle has a private String style.

In our GUI class, we create TableColumns:

```
TableColumn<Professional, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("NAME");
nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
//
TableColumn<Employee, Integer> ageColumn = new TableColumn<>("AGE");
nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("age"));
//
```

Now here's where I'm lost. I'm unable to do:

```
TableColumn<Employee, String> workstyleColumn = new TableColumn<>("WORKSTYLE");
workstyleColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ethic.getStyle()"));
```

There must be SOME way of having:

```
TableColumn<Object Being Looked At, Type being put onto the column> columnTitle = new TableColumn<>(
{
     // I want to put tons of code here which EVENTUALLY ends with a object of type "Type being put onto the column".
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
workstyleColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getEthic().getStyle()));
```

The [`cellValueFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellValueFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) is a `Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures, ObservableValue>`, i.e. a function taking a `TableColumn.CellDataFeatures` and returning an `ObservableValue`. [`CellDataFeatures.getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellDataFeatures.html#getValue--) gives the value for the row, so `cellData.getValue().getEthic().getStyle()` gives the value you want. Finally you wrap it in a `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` to give an `ObservableValue`.

Comment: Odd, it says that "ReadOnlyStringWrapper" cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: What import did you add for it?

Comment: I'm not sure if Eclipse auto added an import for me or not but right now here are my imports: [codepad link](http://codepad.org/zCNuOHkg). I see that I had javafx.util.Callback; and javafx.util.Duration; on there...

Comment: I meant what import did you add when you added the `ReadOnlyStringWrapper`?  In Eclipse you can just do Shift-Control-O and it will figure them out for you (or ask if there are multiple options).

Comment: Ah I found it `import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;`. One last question, what if the item I wanted on my TableView was an image and in Workstyle (for whatever reason) there was a private Image picture. Surely I cannot do: `workstyleColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new ReadOnlyImageWrapper(cellData.getValue().getEthic().getPicture()));`?

Comment: You would use a `new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>` instead of the `ReadOnlyStringWrapper`. And make sure the column were a `TableColumn<Employee, Image>`. (You'd presumably want a `cellFactory` too.)

Answer (score 0):

if your using PropertyValueFactory you need to write the method name without "()".

So you need an Method in Employee wich returns the style of the ethic:

```
class Employee{
      private Ethic ethic;
      .... 

    public String getEthicStyle(){
         return ethic != null ? ethic.getStyle : "";
   }

}
```

and the rest looks like this:

```
TableColumn<Employee, String> workstyleColumn = new TableColumn<>("WORKSTYLE");
workstyleColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ethicStyle"));
```

**EDIT**

@James_D answer isn't wrong but if you realy want to use PropertyValueFactory you have to write the extra Method in Employee

Comment: IMO `PropertyValueFactory` is legacy API anyway and should be avoided in any case. (Look at the number of questions on SO that are basically because of typos in the `PropertyValueFactory` argument or in the property name.) With Java 8 you can do `nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cd -> cd.getValue().nameProperty())` which is properly verified by the compiler, and no more verbose than the `PropertyValueFactory`.

Comment: Yes I know but I just want to show how it works with the PropertyValueFacotry. The cleaner way is surly the Callback.

Comment: How does it know to call the function `getEthicStyle()` by the words `"ethicStyle"`. You didn't put `get` or capitalize `Ethic` in `EthicStyle`.

Comment: The PropertyValue factory searches in the Employee class for the getter of the "property" ethicStyle, what the factory finds is the getter in this case "getEthicStyle". 

What you pass the PropertyValue is the name of the Property not a getter for it:   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html#PropertyValueFactory-java.lang.String-